# Trying to get a div to scroll when a collection of child divs are brought in dynamically

Tags: css

I have a collection of divs being brought into a parent div (which is inside a popup container) dynamically. Sometimes there's only 1 and sometimes there are 6. For anything over 3 child divs, I want the parent to have a scroll bar HORIZONTALLY. The problem is that the child divs wrap instead of continuing on.

The following actually works:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent-container">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #0486A0;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    display: none;
    height: 450px;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 315px;
    top: 407px;
    z-index: 2000000;}

.parent-container{    
    float: left;
    max-width: 670px;
    overflow: auto;}

.parent {
    display: block;
    width: -moz-max-content;}

.child {    
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    }
```

BUT

Notice the -moz-max-content! I can't use this because it only works in Firefox. Max-width doesn't work either.

TL;DR: Is there a workaround for moz-max-content so I don't have to specify a fixed width on my parent div?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the `overflow-y: scroll` css rule.

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp%3a).

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't be a problem

your container should have a maximum width say 800px (set overflow: auto;)
i'd suggest having another div "childContainer" to contain the child divs

when a child is successfully loaded (on $.ajax.success), use jquery to update the width of #childContainer (something like)

```
$("#childContainer").width($("#childContainer").width() + $(child).width());
```

but you'll have to track the number of divs you have loaded.  but it will allow you to dynamically size a div within the container